# how to install "spree-dropdown-variants" with spree 1.1.1

Tags: rubygems, spree

I am using spree 1.1.1 and facing problem installing "spree-dropdown-variants" because it has no GEM file. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fork the project and add a gemspec.

Answer (score 0):

I have forked the GEM and got installed and everything gone well but it has some problem with the javascript.(it is alowing to select the first variant but was unable to select 2nd variant options). No offense **"spree-dropdown-variants"** team the problem might be the versions.

so i have shifted to [spree_flexi_variants](https://github.com/jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants) and have completed my requirement with it.
thanks to spree_flexi_variants team.